# Is there an [api] to help burninate this tag?

Tags: support, burninate-request, blocklist-request

The [api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) tag is typical meta tag. It is used as modal modifier for other tags, but it is used for so many different things, that in no way it could be used alone.

Let's burninate it. Every time someone uses this tag, one frog dies.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is being downvoted. I definitely agree with it's destruction, the tag serves no purpose!

Comment: Well, someone thinks this tag is useful, but it would be nice to write a reason as an answer (and risk downvotes ^^)

Comment: Of course, I do love tag destruction in general, so maybe my vote doesn't mean as much?

Comment: Hmm don't know if I agree or disagree. hmmmmmmm so tough. well no vote either way from me then.

Comment: If you burninate the tag, there would be hundreds of new tags will be geneerated like: google-api, paypal-api,facebook-api, etc, etc...

Comment: @MidhunMP I think it's better to have a hundred of meaningful tags that one so vague that it's practically meaningless.

Comment: @ŁukaszLech: I understand and partially agree with you. But what happens when a general question like: Creaing an API for iOS, integrating third party API's to blahblahblah etc ?

Comment: @MidhunMP would it make sense to use only [api] tag in that case? If not, it's not an appropriate tag.

Comment: @Midhun MP: Half of them aren't even... new.

Comment: @benisuqbackwards: Problem is the close reason (which would really depend on the tag) for doing an auto-close.  You'd have to supply that information with each tag, and the script isn't designed for that now.  Autodownvoting is kinda dicky, so I wouldn't do that.  You have to close every tab, and should review what you did, so downvoting and voting to close/delete is something that can be included in your workflow.

Comment: @Won't you've forgotten to say that your script requires 10k rep, because it uses inline tag edits.

Comment: @ŁukaszLech Interesting.  I'll add that to the description.  Thanks!

Comment: It should be safe to remove [tag:api] from [all questions already tagged with \[\*-api\]](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bapi%5D+%5B*-api%5D+is%3Aquestion), without looking into the questions in too much (any) detail.

Comment: **API** tag is definitely useful (only if combined with other tags) because simply there are many missing [*-api] tags :)

Comment: If I shouldn't use the API tag, than what tag should I use for a question about trying to connect to an API from say, Powershell or some other script/code base?

Comment: @Ellesedil Perhaps [powershell-api] or [some other script/code base-api]...

Comment: @Ellesedil: What do you mean, "connect to an API"? This very phrasing suggests that you are talking about connecting to a service that exposes an API - and I am sure that we can find a better name for that. (e.g. [web-api] may be a good fit, depending on the specifics of the API.)

Answer (score 27):

This is an old request, but it's worth resurrecting in my opinion.

The current description of this tag reads:

> DO NOT USE: Tag with the library you mean, [api-design], or something else appropriate instead.

That alone should tell you that this tag should go.

This tag draws a massive number of off-topic recommendation questions on an almost-daily basis.

It's also *very* vague, adding no useful information whatsoever.

I say that we should burn it.

Comment: Three years later, this meta page is still linked in the api tag wiki. It looks like nothing has been done on this. Is there something preventing the tag from getting deleted?

Comment: @GeneralGrievance People. We do not have enough people to dive into a burnination of nearly 100000 questions. Your comment is old, but at the time of your writing, a second problem was that no one was doing burninations. They've resumed now, but a burnination this massive requires a level of coordination we currently cannot do. On that note, my personal hope is that resuming burninations, over time, will result in more involvement to make this feasible. I'll also have to check if we can get CMs or devs involved in some way to make this less miserable, but that's something to do down the road

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine Yeah, I made that comment before I ever got involved in any serious burnination process or really knew what that involved. Definitely makes a lot more sense now that I've helped out with a couple.

Answer (score -6):

There's not even a need to go through the questions. The tag can be just removed because *all* SO questions are either about API use or API design.

Answer (score -17):

I'm not good with destroying information. I realize that the tag [api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) is not useful on its own. But isn't the real problem here that we can't search on more than one tag at a time?

There may come a time when searching on multiple tags is possible. Then we might be crying over all the information we destroyed by burninating the [api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) tag!

**EDIT:**

Ahah! I just discovered that you can search on multiple tags at the same time.

So I can search on [java][api] to find questions/answers specifically about the java api and not other irrelevant stuff.

Comment: Today, September 12: a search [java][api] returns questions that ask about: the design of the Java standard API, finding an API (that is, a library) to manipulate `wav` files in Java, using the Bing Search API from Java, API design in Java, using the Wechat API, accessing a particular method defined in a Java API from Scala... The tag is used in hopelessly different ways.