# Revisiting the [api] tag

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

Every time I see a post come through tagged with [api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) I think of this: [Is there an [api] to help burninate this tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255437/burninate-the-api-tag-in-stack-overflow)

And instead of one frog dying every time someone posts to that tag, *I* think of stabbing a frog each time I see the ALL CAPS WARNING!!! on its description:

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG!!!

[image]

Let's be honest: APIs, in the conventional sense, rule. But [Web] APIs in the "I made an HTTP call and got some JSON from some cool guy (not Batman)" sense are bad-ass and are likely to stick around until someone discovers that you can send microscopic squirrels down series of tubes much more efficiently than HTTP can.

BUT: does this tag really need to exist in limbo with a big ugly sign on its door that tells people not to use it (*which I might add they don't listen to anyway!*)?

Or could we improve the tag description to explain the *clear* distinction between "Programing Language API" and "Web API HTTP Request To Get JSON <s>and XML</s>".

Maybe something like this?

> API can mean a lot of different things these days. We use it on Stack Overflow as a "meta" tag - meaning it works best if you combine it with other tags, e.g. [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) [api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) or [twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter) [api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api).
>
> "API" in this sense is ambiguous. The conventional meaning of API is:
>
> *The original description*
>
> But "API" is also colloquially used to talk about Web APIs [insert more paraphrased content from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface#Web_APIs]

I realize that that doesn't exactly roll off the tongue. But perhaps, since the burninate was asked 2 years ago, we can collectively come up with a better description for poor ol' [api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api)?

Answer (score 7):

[api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) should just be taken out from orbit and blacklisted.

It's a meta-tag (It doesn't contribute anything to categorizing questions), there are too many to manually take care of, and it will be re-created by some bozo in a second.

If any question looses its last tag that way, well, at least this way someone will find it and correct that.

Comment: Well, blacklist would sure be better than leaving it in limbo. Either way, it's just frog-stabbing awful the way it is now!