# Should we burninate [customapi]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I just ran across [customapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/customapi) which has no tag wiki and 14 questions. It looks to be a little, barely used, brother of [api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) whose tag excerpt already says "DO NOT USE" and is discussed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255437/5211833). Given that a 'custom API' is about as broad as a non-custom API, should we take care of it now, since there's just 14 questions, instead of letting it grow to 60k questions?

Comment: I'm in favor to let things grow and blossom ...

Comment: @rene: But after that, things might become a bit blurry ;)

Comment: [api-design] seems an even better fit for [customapi] than for [api], where it is already referenced as an alternative...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[When to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191) :

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?** and **is it unambiguous?**

No and no. This is already sufficient grounds for burnination as it defines a "meta-tag". The correct tag(s) to use is about the technologies involved in that "API" (SOAP, REST, language(s)/frameworks).

2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

More like it isn't than is. Questions about API design are programming.SE's topic. Implementing or using an API are rather about using the technologies involved.

3. **Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?**

No. It doesn't even say if the question is about using or designing the API.  Likewise, the fact that an API is being designed for some specific customer(s) or for some random app is completely unrelated to technical details.

4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No. Every API can be considered "custom" to a varying extent.

---

Since the number of tagged questions is small, I've removed/replaced the tag manually.